# Excel VBA import of various excel files to master sheet

Tags: excel, import, vba

I have a master Excel workbook and I want to create a macro to import data from a specified range from 7 Excel files. These files are all the same in structure except for the actual data. With the import macro/button I basically want to get an open files dialogue, select all the files and let the macro add the data in the range to the master one by one. I have taken some Inspiration from another post here, which makes it work for one single file: The to be adjusted code would have to be able to select the 7 files and dynamically add it to the target range one by one.

```
 Sub getData()

Dim slaveBook As Workbook
Dim filter As String
Dim caption As String
Dim slaveFilename As String
Dim slaveWorkbook As Workbook
Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook

Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

filter = "Team file (*.xlsm),*.xlsm"
caption = "Please select the team file"
slaveFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , caption)

Set slaveWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(slaveFilename)

Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets("MASTER")
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Set sourceSheet = slaveWorkbook.Worksheets("Interface")

targetSheet.Range("B5", "J8").Value = sourceSheet.Range("B5", "J8").Value


slaveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Do your files move file location at all? If they don't why dont you store the file locations in an array and loop the array through the code to perform the macro on all 7 workbooks

Comment: thanks for the idea. The files will potentially move Locations, thus I'll have to built it in this way unfortunately. Right now I think it just Needs to be able to Loop through the files and add the ranges to the master range one by one

Comment: the problem you'll face is that in order to "loop" you'll need to tell VBA where the file path is, or get the user to select the workbook on every workbook loop

Comment: I think the latter would be okay. How would I have to adapt the code for that?

Comment: How are you collecting your data on the MASTER sheet? If the above code was looped, it would overwrite the previous slaveworkbook's data in the MASTER sheet. Will you have 7 Master sheets? Or are you putting the information in seperate columns ect

Comment: yeah exactly the code I have right now only lets me choose one Excel slave and even if it would select me various ones it would overwrite the same range over and over again. There's only the one master sheet. Basically what I have defined as sourceSheet.Range stays the same for every slave book. The targetSheet.Range would have to be dynamic. Essentially the first slave range would be added in B5:J8 in the master file, the second one below that and so on

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub getData()

Dim slaveBook As Workbook
Dim filter As String
Dim caption As String
Dim slaveFilename As String
Dim slaveWorkbook As Workbook
Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook

i = 1

For i = 1 To 7

Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

On Error GoTo errorhandler

filter = "Team file (*.xlsm),*.xlsm"
caption = "Please select the team file"
slaveFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , caption)

Set slaveWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(slaveFilename)
On Error GoTo 0

On Error GoTo err2
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets("MASTER")
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Set sourceSheet = slaveWorkbook.Worksheets("Interface")

If i = 1 Then targetSheet.Range("B5", "J8").Value = sourceSheet.Range("B5", "J8").Value
If i = 2 Then targetSheet.Range("B9", "J12").Value = sourceSheet.Range("B5", "J8").Value
If i = 3 Then targetSheet.Range("B13", "J16").Value = sourceSheet.Range("B5", "J8").Value
If i = 4 Then targetSheet.Range("B17", "J20").Value = sourceSheet.Range("B5", "J8").Value
If i = 5 Then targetSheet.Range("B21", "J24").Value = sourceSheet.Range("B5", "J8").Value
If i = 6 Then targetSheet.Range("B25", "J28").Value = sourceSheet.Range("B5", "J8").Value
If i = 7 Then targetSheet.Range("B29", "J32").Value = sourceSheet.Range("B5", "J8").Value


slaveWorkbook.Close False 'wont prompt to save changes (will close without saving),
                          'remove false if you do need to save changes

i = i + 1

Next i

Exit Sub

errorhandler:

MsgBox "You didn't select a valid file!"
Exit Sub

err2:
MsgBox "Error - Most likely reason is that the required sheet is not found in Slave workbook"
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

**Updated** - Have changed the code so now it should save all the information to your "MASTER" sheet underneath eachother. Obviously this is a very simple way of doing it, and restricts you to only opening 7 files before the code ends. If you wanted to add more in the future you could simply extend the array and range code or modify the range code to look for the last available row to paste data on (`LastRow = Range("J65536").End(xlUp).Row`) is a good place to start

Comment: Thank you for that! However I do need the data from the slave files all in one master, all in one table. Basically what Needs to be dynamic is the targetSheet.Range. sourceSheet.Range is the same for every slave. But I'd need the Loop to copy each sourceSheet.Range below the previous one. So if the first one starts at B5:J8, the data from the next file would have to be copied below that and so on

Comment: @user3696409 - Please see modified answer